# Does successful Glyph Hacks have any effect on the drop rates of rare items?

Tags: ingress

I already know that if you glyph hack, and are successful, you are awarded bonus items. However, most of these items are the common items, and I've noticed that the occurrence of rare items are the same as if you were not to glyph hack (of course, you would just receive less common items).

Is this true (or is it just my imagination?), and is there any data to back it up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is same. My experience is that you won't get any advantage on rare (vr) items.

You can read about this here:

http://ingress.wikia.com/wiki/Glyph_Hacking

and here

https://fevgames.net/ingress/ingress-guide/actions/glyph-hack/

> Community studies suggest that the composition of bonus items is identical to that of standard hack items and that every 30% of glyph or speed bonus, rounded up, causes another item roll to be added to the bonus. The rolls are made independently, and the agent can receive multiple copies of the same Very Rare or sponsored item.

One of the power of the glyph when you are with your friends, and there are 3-4 portals in range, make a farm (lvl 8 portals), and put frackers into the portals. Then heat sink, heat sink, heat sink, vr multihack. But this is another topic. And I hope, you are enlightened :)

Comment: I, an Enlightened have been enlightened. ;)

Comment: Have upvotes for picking the *correct* team